# How to determine the size of a SQL Server database for a specific date in the past?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard

What I would like to find out is what the size of the DB was at specific dates in the past.  I don't have backups going back that far. The current log may or may not go back far enough.

Is there any way at all to retrieve that type of information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you capture that information on your own SQL Server does not record it anywhere. Most folks go by the backup size.

If you use 3rd party software to backup the server or where ever you store your database backups you might see if it has a history as well. If you have something like Netbackup Enterprise or other similar software it should keep at most the file name and size unless your backup admins purge that information as well, but most don't that I have worked with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had figured as much but wanted to run it by the DBA community to make sure I didn't miss anything.  The backups don't go back far enough in our case.

Comment: If you don't have a purge job set up, you can find all your backup sizes in msdb.dbo.backupset; I've used it to backtrack database sizes many times.